# Can I define a javascript variable (not global) inside a function and this variable be visible ouside his scope?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I need to define a variable inside a function and this same variable must be visible in his original scope and one scope above (it's not the same as global variable).

It's possible in javascript?

**eg.**

```
function mainFunction () {

    function firstFunction() {
      var var1 = 10;
      secondFunction();
      console.log(var2); // must be 20 (must be undefined one scope above  firstFunction())
      console.log(var1); // must be 10 (of course)
    }

    function secondFunction() {
      var var2 = 20;
      console.log(var2); // must be 20 (of course)
      console.log(var1); // must be undefined
    }

    firstFunction();

    console.log(var2); // must be undefined
    console.log(var1); // must be undefined

}
```

Comment: Your code is missing `var` so those are globals anyway, but the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: What Pointy said is accurate here. None of the (currently 6 or 7 already) answers are correct and/or applicable to your question.

Comment: Thanks. If fixed the variable declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Using ES6 you can block scope these functions. This gives a "global" variable defined in a specific block, and leaves it accessible to functions defined in this scope.

```
{
    let var1 = 10;
    function one() {
        //...
    }
    function two() {
        //...
    }
}
```

This allows you to have simple and effective control over your scope, especially when it comes to hoisting and functions.

Edit to your edit: Unless you pass `var2` as a parameter to the function, there's no way to scope it to 2 functions without some sort of upper level scoping. Aka, firstFunction can not have access to var2 (again, unless parametered), without the mainFunction having scope to it.

Comment: Downvoters, could you please explain? I'm new to ES6 so I'd love to learn what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`secondFunction()` is outside `firstFunction()` scope, so your comment

```
// must be 20 (must be undefined outside firstFunction() scope)
```

would mean that `var2` can never be accessible to `secondFunction()`

Comment: Sorry. What I meant is: "must be undefined one scope above firstFunction()". Thanks, I fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It will work like you have commented it in your code. The function scope does not propagate into global scope.

Why not declare the variables at the top?

```
var var1, var2;
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be using a static variable, for example

```
function firstFunction() {
    firstFunction.var1 = 10;
}

// you can access firstFunction.var1 outside the firstFunction()
```

...but of course this is sort of a gimmicky way to do it.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... tried to make a code block comment, but i'm still a bit new with this :/

Answer (score 0):

In javascript ,private variables can be made possible to access with closures. A closure is a function having access to the parent scope, even after the parent function has closed.

```
function mainFunction () {

    function firstFunction() {
       var var1 = 10;
       var var2 = secondFunction();
       console.log(var2); // must be 20 
       console.log(var1); // must be 10 (of course)
    }

    function secondFunction() {
        var var2 = 20;
      console.log(var2); // must be 20 (of course)
      return var2;
    }

    firstFunction();

   // console.log(var2); // must be undefined
   // console.log(var1); // must be undefined

}

mainFunction();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

Answer (score -2):

use

```
window.var1
window.var2
```

instead

Comment: OP  specifically requests to not have it be in the global scope. Attaching to `window` would do that.